# readline function in .net assembler

Tags: .net, il

I'm trying to figure il code out, but cannot understand why next code crashed. When I use the same code without next row:`call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()` code behavior are expected, but adding above described row force crash. What's wrong in this statement??

```
.assembly Hello {}
    .method public static void SomeFunction() cil managed
    {
         .entrypoint
         ldstr "Hello, world!"
         call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
         call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
         ret
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you write the code in C# and looked at the IL for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadLine is returning string, so I guess there should be "pop" before ret ?